# Optimisation of an oracle query

Tags: oracle, join, linked-server

I'm trying to make my query run as quickly as possible but i'm struggling to get it under 5 seconds.

I think it's because i'm referencing two linked databases

Here's my query

```
select column2, column3, column4 
  from table1@dev 
 where column1 in (
          select distinct column2 
            from table2@dev 
           where column3 > 0
                  ) 
order by column1
```

Is there a way to optimise this query any more?

I've tried using `join` but it seems to make the query run longer

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

From further investigation the `DRIVING_SITE` makes it run very quick like this

```
select /*+ DRIVING_SITE(table1) */ t1.column2, t1.column3, t1.column4
from table1@dev t1, table2@dev t2
WHERE t2.column3 > 0
```

But as soon as I add the `distinct column2` in it makes it run really slow

Comment: You may want to investigate the `DRIVING_SITE` hint. http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF50704

Comment: You don't need the `distinct` inside the `IN (SELECT ...)`

Comment: What indexes do you have on the 2 tables?

Comment: @ypercube column2 is the index for both tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, no need for `distinct`. The query can be written as:

```
select * 
  from table1@dev 
 where column1 in (
          select column2 
            from table2@dev 
           where column3 > 0
                  ) 
order by column1
```

Second, there are (at least) two more ways to write it. Either with `JOIN`:

```
select t1.* 
  from table1@dev t1
  join table2@dev t2
 where t2.column2 = t1.column1
   and t2.column3 > 0 
group by
       t1.id, t1.column1, ... 

order by t1.column1
```

or (my preference) with `EXISTS`:

```
select t1.* 
  from table1@dev t1 
 where exists
       ( select *
           from table2@dev 
          where t2.column2 = t1.column1
            and t2.column3 > 0
                  ) 
order by column1
```

---

In any case, you should check the execution plans for all of them.

I would expect performance to be best if you have an index on `table1.column1` and for `table2`, either an index on `column2` or a composite index on `(column3, column2)`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Shannon above , but are you able to create a view on the dev server ?

Also *select ** is a bit naughty - it is better to name the fields you really want.  For very large datasets that will give you a performance improvement too.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something in believing that this will work?

```
select t1.* 
from table1 t1, table2 t2 
where t1.column1 = t2.column2(+) 
and t2.column3 > 0;
```