# Selecting column from an exists statement

Tags: sql, oracle, exists

This is a follow-up to my previous question: [Optimisation of an oracle query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7310805/372364)

I am now using the query as follows

```
select t1.column1, t2.column2 
    from table1@dev t1 
  where exists
         ( select *
              from table2@dev 
            where t2.column2 = t1.column1
              and t2.column3 > 0
                    ) 
order by column1
```

But the problem is I can't access `column2` from `t2` i'm getting the error

> t2.column2 invalid identifier

Is it possible to access the column from this table when using `EXISTS`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you already know the column is equal to t1.column1 for the chosen rows. So why not refer to that ? SELECT t1.column1, t1.column1 as column2 ....

Comment: Some of the data that's in `table1` isn't in `table2` and i only want the data from `table2` for that column every other column i need from `table1`... hope that makes sense?

Comment: I'll try and explain... `table1` has 35 records and `table2` has 30 records. I want to select the records from `table2` but also select some other data from `table1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Exists` (as the name implies) merely checks if that thing exists, it does not return any data beyond the true/false of the existence predicate, so **no**, it's not possible to return data from an `exists` statement.

To select something from multiple tables, you need to join them, like this:

```
select t1.column1, t2.column2      
  from table1@dev t1    
    inner join table2@dev t2 on t2.column2 = t1.column1
 where t2.column3 > 0
 order by t1.column1
```

Comment: If you are joining a 30 row table with a 35 row table, and it's taking ages, the problem is elsewhere. If the columns you are joining on are indexed, this should return almost instantly even if the row count is in the millions.

Comment: I took out the link to the second table and the query still took ages so problem seems to be elsewhere - Will mark your post as answer as it helped - Thanks